# How to solve error during installation Gulp via npm?

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, frontend, node-modules

Running

```
npm i gulp
```

Inside the project. Packages start installing but I get the following error message soon:

```
npm ERR! code E500
npm ERR! 500 javax.servlet.ServletException: org.sonatype.nexus.blobstore.api.BlobStoreException: BlobId: d5da3b0d-b346-409b-8a9a-484ce517b3d7, Blob has been deleted: flatmap-stream@0.1.2
```

What's wrong with it and how to make **gulp** to be installed?

Last rows of debug log are here:

```
24713 verbose stack Error: 500 javax.servlet.ServletException: org.sonatype.nexus.blobstore.api.BlobStoreException: BlobId: d5da3b0d-b346-409b-8a9a-484ce517b3d7, Blob has been deleted: flatmap-stream@0.1.2
24713 verbose stack     at fetch.then.res (C:\Users\syampolskiy\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\fetchers\registry\fetch.js:42:19)
24713 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (C:\Users\syampolskiy\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
24713 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Users\syampolskiy\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
24713 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Users\syampolskiy\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
24713 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Users\syampolskiy\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
24713 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Users\syampolskiy\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:694:18)
24713 verbose stack     at _drainQueueStep (C:\Users\syampolskiy\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:138:12)
24713 verbose stack     at _drainQueue (C:\Users\syampolskiy\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:131:9)
24713 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueues (C:\Users\syampolskiy\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:147:5)
24713 verbose stack     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (C:\Users\syampolskiy\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
24713 verbose stack     at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
24713 verbose stack     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
24713 verbose stack     at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
24714 verbose cwd D:\domains\projectname\knorr\project-platform
24715 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
24716 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\syampolskiy\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "i"
24717 verbose node v10.14.2
24718 verbose npm  v6.5.0
24719 error code E500
24720 error 500 javax.servlet.ServletException: org.sonatype.nexus.blobstore.api.BlobStoreException: BlobId: d5da3b0d-b346-409b-8a9a-484ce517b3d7, Blob has been deleted: flatmap-stream@0.1.2
24721 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Looks like you're installing from a private nexus registry instead of the public npm registry. The admins responsible for running that nexus registry should be able to help you

Comment: @PatrickHund thank you! what admins do you mean? I have a repository (created not by me) and I must install all dependencies in it. Maybe I can do it by myself?

Comment: Which registry do you have configured in your `.npmrc` or `package.json` file? I was assuming it's not the default (public npm registry at registry.npmjs.org), but some other registry, which is throwing the error when you try installing packages.